# What is the deal with offering an animal for sin offering - seems mostly male, but some female instructions exist. see Lev 4:28

Tags: sacrifice, offering

> Lev 4:28 if his sin which he has committed is made known to him, then
> he shall bring for his offering a goat, a female without defect, for
> his sin which he has committed

Is there a principle here regarding using a male animal vs a female?

Obviously Jesus is male, so there is a type there. I was surprised to see that females were allowed also.

Comment: Males of almost any species are usually physically stronger, the idea being that lesser sins require lesser sacrifices.

Comment: thx, but expecting some solid references from the *learned* crowd here

Answer (score 1):

Leviticus 4

> 22“ ‘When a **leader** sins unintentionally and does what is forbidden in any of the commands of the Lord his God, when he realizes his guilt 23and the sin he has committed becomes known, he must bring as his offering a **male** goat without defect.

> 27“ ‘If any **member of the community** sins unintentionally and does what is forbidden in any of the Lord’s commands, when they realize their guilt 28and the sin they have committed becomes known, they must bring as their offering for the sin they committed a **female** goat without defect.

For unintentional sins, the gender of the sacrificial animal depends on the kind of person who committed the sin. For persons who are in the higher echelon, they sacrifice a male. For the common people, they sacrifice a female.

> Leviticus 27:1 The Lord said to Moses, 2“Speak to the Israelites and say to them: ‘If anyone makes a special vow to dedicate a person to the Lord by giving the equivalent value, 3set the value of a **male** between the ages of twenty and sixty at **fifty shekels** a of silver, according to the sanctuary shekel; 4for a **female**, set her value at **thirty shekels**.

Males are valued more than females but both are acceptable as dedicated to the Lord.

Comment: thx, interesting! Can we put that as *anecdotal* evidence so far?

Comment: I have added some.

Answer (score 0):

further to Tony's useful answer,

The **burnt** offering is to be a male (Leviticus 3:1,5 ) The burnt offering symbolising the complete sacrifice - as per Jesus

While a peace offering can be either male or female - or if you cannot afford an animal (even two birds) then a flour offering is acceptable) It seems only part of the animal is used for sacrifice while the rest is for the priests.